# Image Feature Extraction - Preprocessing

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I found this awesome open source image recognition framework - [Pastec](https://github.com/Visu4link/pastec), and it worked out really well in a way where I took a video of an object, and sample 10% of the video frames and it can recognize the rest of the videos pretty well.

However, after I indexed the video and took another photo in a complete different environment, it couldn't recognize it even if to me they look extremely similar.

Do I need to apply some basic processing like thresholding(binary), smoothing, and maybe contouring before feature extracting and indexing? also, if that is the case, I probably also need to apply the same technique before query.

Here I am taking almost a 360 degree video of the product and index all the frames in the database, hopefully that searched picture will be of an angle that appeared in the training data.

[image]

In the project, it mentioned "not been designed to recognize faces, 3D objects, barcodes, or QR codes.", I don't know if I am wasting time here using this software or is there any other approach/tool/techniques that I need to adopt.

Answer (score 0):

Pastec is based on [Visual Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Word) which in turn uses local descriptor such as [SIFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) or [SURF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speeded_up_robust_features). Those two are not fully rotational invariant, and will most probably fail altogether if the view point is different.

Difference in lighting will have, obviously, a huge impact on the recognition capability as well. Preprocessing may help a little, but not so much, unfortunately. I would personnally use a statistical or neural net approach for such a problem.

Comment: Just to mention, pastec uses ORB ;D

Comment: @Miki well that may explain a lot, as SIFT and SURF are usually much better.

Comment: yep, but patented ;D

Comment: before I dump a table of 1080*1920~2million columns to a neural network, should I do any PCA or SVD to do some dimension reduction? Or, should I directly crop all the images after identifying the contour considering all the images will have a whitebackground to make sure object is all over the image.